# crud thru pivot wont update

Tags: php, laravel

So i am currently creating a laravel environment using pivot table's. But if i update information of table 'tags' it wont update the data in the table 'file' where it shows the name of the 'tags' row.
Image of the database is down below.

So basically. my file Read function shows. id, title, desc_long, desc_short, tags.

this works fine but if i update a tag it still shows the old name of the tag.

tagcontroller:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
      
          $tags = Tag::all();
          $tagEdit = Tag::find($id);
          return view('admin.tag.index', compact('tagEdit', 'tags'));
        
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'color'=>'required',
        ]);

        $tagData = [
         'name' => $request->name,
         'color' => $request->color
        ];

        Tag::whereId($id)->update($tagData);
        return redirect()->route('admin.tag.index');

    }
```

FileController:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $files = File::with('subfolder', 'role', 'tag')->get();
        $subfolders = Subfolder::all();
        $languages = Language::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $users = User::all();
        $roles = Role::all();
     //   dd($files);
      
        return view('admin.file.index', compact('files', 'subfolders', 'languages', 'tags', 'users', 'roles' ));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description_short' => '',
            'description_long' => '',
            'file' => 'mimes:pdf,xlsx,docx,pptx',
          
        ]);
        if ($request->file) {
            //dd($request);
            $file = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

            $file_name = $file . '.' . $request->file->extension();

            $document = new File([
                'title' => $request->get('title'),
                'description_short' => $request->get('description_short'),
                'description_long' => $request->get('description_long'),
                'file' => 'storage/files/' . $file_name,
               
            ]);
            $request->file->move(public_path('storage/files/'), $file_name);
        } else {
            $document = new File([
                'title' => $request->get('title'),
                'description_short' => $request->get('description_short'),
                'description_long' => $request->get('description_long'),
                'file' => $request->get('file'),
            
            ]);
        }
        $document->save();
        $document->subfolder()->attach($request->get('subfolder_id'));
        $document->role()->attach($request->get('role_id'));
        $document->role()->attach($request->get('tag_id'));

        return back();
    }
```

index.blade (where i show the crud)

```
  @foreach($files as $file)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$file->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$file->title}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->description_short}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->description_long}} </td>
            <td>{{$file->file}}</td>
            <td>{{@$file->language->name}} </td>
            @foreach($file->tag as $tags)
            <td>{{@$tags->name}} </td>
            @endforeach
            <td>
```

File model:

```
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subfolder::class, 'file_tag', 'file_id', 'tag_id')->withPivot('id');
    }
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'file_role', 'file_id', 'role_id')->withPivot('id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    

    protected $table = 'file';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description_short',
        'description_long',
        'file',
        'subfolder_id',

    ];
}
```

[image]

Comment: in database tag_id is updated ?

Comment: tag_id stays the same as i only edit the tag name

Comment: share your File model

Comment: updated and added

Answer (score 0):

i changed

```
public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subfolder::class, 'file_tag', 'file_id', 'tag_id')->withPivot('id');
    }
```

to

```
public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'file_tag', 'file_id', 'tag_id')->withPivot('id');
    }
```